# I'm trying to save the value of a spinner to a file but I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: kivy, spyder, kivy-language

I'm trying to make an app to charge some e-bikes with an universal charger. So the user needs an account, at the registration they chose the e-bike they have out of the options in the spinner. This value needs to be stored at a user-file so it can be used later. The problem is when I try to save the account I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

When I delete everything of saving the values of the spinner the program works perfectly. 
Can someone help me with this problem?

part of the main app ULiVEmain.py

```
class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):      #create an account
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    bikebrand = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.namee.text != "" and self.email.text != "" and self.email.text.count("@") == 1 and self.email.text.count(".") > 0:
            if self.password != "":
                db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.namee.text, self.bikebrand.text)

                self.reset()
                sm.current = "login_screen"
            else:
                invalidForm()
        else:
            invalidForm()

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "login_screen"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""
        self.namee.text = ""

    def spinnerBrand(self, text):
        print("Brand of the bike is: " + text)

kv = Builder.load_file("LayoutULiVEApp.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("users.txt")
```

py-file to save the accountdata: database.py

```
import datetime

class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.users = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.users = {}

        for line in self.file:
            email, password, name, created, bikebrand= line.strip().split(";")
            self.users[email] = (password, name, created, bikebrand)

        self.file.close()

    def get_user(self, email):
        if email in self.users:
            return self.users[email]
        else:
            return -1

    def add_user(self, email, password, name, bikebrand):
        if email.strip() not in self.users:
            self.users[email.strip()] = (password.strip(), name.strip(), bikebrand.strip(), DataBase.get_date())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            print("Email exists already")
            return -1

    def validate(self, email, password):
        if self.get_user(email) != -1:
            return self.users[email][0] == password
        else:
            return False

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            for user in self.users:
                f.write(user + ";" + self.users[user][0] + ";" + self.users[user][1] + ";" + self.users[user][2] + ";" +self.users[user][3] + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
```

part of the kv-file, to create an account

```
<CreateAccountWindow>
    name: "create"

    namee: namee
    email: email
    password: passw

    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Label:
                text: "Create an Account"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":1}
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.26,0.15
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Name: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.76}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.08
                id: namee
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.26,0.15
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.7}
                text: "Email: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.66}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.08
                id: email
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.2,0.15
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.6}
                text: "Password: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.56}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.08
                id: passw
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.26,0.15
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
                text: "Bike: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Spinner:
                id: bikebrand
                on_text:
                    root.spinnerBrand(bikebrand.text)   
                text: "<Select>"
                values: ['Brand A', 'Brand B', 'Brand C', 'Brand D', 'Brand E', 'Brand F', 'Brand G', 'Brand H', 'Brand I']
                background_color: 1,1,1,1
                color: 0,0,0,1
                color_down: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.08
                pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.46}

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.25}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 15**4
                text: "Already have an Account? Log In"
                background_color: 0.68, 0.8, 0.5, 0.18
                color: 0,0,0,1
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.login()

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.12
                text: "Submit"
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                background_color: 0.68, 0.8, 0.5, 0.18
                color: 0,0,0,1
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.submit()
```

Comment: Does the error message indicate which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that, in code it gives fault in line 29 in main: db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.namee.text, self.bikebrand.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` file, you haven't defined the `ObjectProperty` `bikebrand`. I believe you only need to change:

```
namee: namee
email: email
password: passw
```

to include the `bikebrand`:

```
namee: namee
email: email
password: passw
bikebrand: bikebrand
```